# Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf

Tags: javascript, c#, devexpress

Tengo un reporte creado con la librería de DevExpress v 17.1, como se muestra en la siguiente imagen:

[image: 1]]

Pero al momento de darle clic al botón de imprimir me manda una alerta en consola diciendo:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type
>   application/pdf

Y no abre la ventana modal para imprimir.

Ese error es usando el navegador Chrome, en cambio usando Opera me sale el siguiente error:

> 12836 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of null

Estuve buscando ese tipo de error pero la mayoría de las respuestas eran acerca de 'application/zip', para descargar archivos y yo no ocupo descargar, sino imprimir.

Los métodos que uso para el reporte de devexpress son los siguientes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using MiModelo.Models;

namespace Ordenes_de_Compra.Reportes
{
    public partial class LabelReport : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        Models.Reportes rpt = new Models.Reportes();
        OrdenCompraDB objDB = new OrdenCompraDB();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int idreq=Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
            var rep = new Requisicion();

            if (Convert.ToInt32(objDB.SelectCadena("select count(*) as resultado from NombreTabla where idreq="+idreq))>0)
            {
                rep.PintarFleteAereo();
            }

            rep.DataSource = LlenarDatos(idreq);
            bool alerta = false;

            foreach (var item in rpt.Tabla1)
            {
                alerta = item.observaciones.ToUpper().Contains("REQUISICIÓN SIN PRESUPUESTO, REQUIERE AUTORIZACIÓN");
                rep.PintarOrigen(item.planta);
                if (item.fechaentrega == "01/01/1900")
                    rep.FechaNula();
            }

            rep.MarcarPresupuesto(objDB.SelectCadena("select isnull(NombreCampo,'') as resultado from NombreTabla where idreq=" + idreq), alerta);
            rep.EsProductoQuimico(objDB.SelectCadena("select isnull(NombreCampo,'') as resultado from NombreTabla where idreq=" + idreq), alerta);
            rep.asignaSubReporte(LlenarCuentas(idreq), Convert.ToInt32(objDB.SelectCadena("select count(*) as resultado from NombreTabla where idreq="+idreq)));              
            this.Visor.Report = rep;
            this.Visor.Report.PageWidth = 2480;
            this.Visor.Report.PageHeight = 3508;
        }

        public Models.Reportes LlenarDatos(int idreq)
        {
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OCEntities"].ConnectionString;          
            string prov = string.Empty;

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                con.Open();

                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("exec ProcedimientoAlmacenado "+idreq, con);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
                da.Fill(rpt.Tabla1);

                foreach (var item in rpt.Tabla1)
                {
                    prov = item.idproveedor;
                }

                SqlCommand com2 = new SqlCommand("exec ProcedimientoAlmacenado '" + prov + "',2",con);
                SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(com2);              
                da2.Fill(rpt.DatosProveedor);

                SqlCommand com3 = new SqlCommand("exec ProcedimientoAlmacenado " + idreq, con);
                SqlDataAdapter da3 = new SqlDataAdapter(com3);
                da3.Fill(rpt.ConceptosReq);

                SqlCommand com4 = new SqlCommand("select Campo1,Campo2,Campo3,Campo4 from NombreTabla where idreq=" + idreq, con);
                SqlDataAdapter da4 = new SqlDataAdapter(com4);
                da4.Fill(rpt.FleteAereo);
                con.Close();
            }        
            return rpt;
        }

        public Models.Reportes LlenarCuentas(int idreq)
        {
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OCEntities"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand com4 = new SqlCommand("exec ProcedimientoAlmacenado " + idreq, con);
                SqlDataAdapter da4 = new SqlDataAdapter(com4);

                da4.Fill(rpt.Cuentas);
                con.Close();
            }         
            return rpt;
        }

    }
}
```

Y este el el HTML que me proporciona DevExpress del reporte:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="LabelReport.aspx.cs" Inherits="Ordenes_de_Compra.Reportes.LabelReport" %>

<%@ Register namespace="DevExpress.Web" tagprefix="Web" %>
<%@ Register assembly="DevExpress.XtraReports.v17.1.Web, Version=17.1.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" namespace="DevExpress.XtraReports.Web" tagprefix="dx" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Reporte Req</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="height:2000px; width:100%">

        <dx:ASPxDocumentViewer ID="Visor" runat="server" EnableTheming="True" Height="100%" Theme="Metropolis" Width="100%" ToolbarMode="Ribbon">
        </dx:ASPxDocumentViewer>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código con el que manipulas el archivo?

Comment: Es un reporte de devexpress, y solo implemento cosas de sus librerías, en todo caso lo único que uso de código es para llenar la tabla, pero no creo que eso sea lo que afecte el que no pueda imprimir :(

Comment: Por favor añade el código para saber qué estás haciendo.

Comment: Listo, ya agregué todos los métodos que uso en el reporte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución a mi problema fue agregando este código javascript en el HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function init(s) {
        var createFrameElement = s.viewer.printHelper.createFrameElement;
        s.viewer.printHelper.createFrameElement = function (name) {
            var frameElement = createFrameElement.call(this, name);
            if (ASPx.Browser.Chrome) {
                frameElement.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
                    if (frameElement.contentDocument && frameElement.contentDocument.contentType !== "text/html")
                        frameElement.contentWindow.print();
                });
            }
            return frameElement;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Y dentro del BODY agregué esto:

```
<dx:ASPxDocumentViewer ID="Visor" runat="server" EnableTheming="True" Height="100%" Theme="Metropolis" Width="100%" ToolbarMode="Ribbon">
            <ClientSideEvents Init="init" />
</dx:ASPxDocumentViewer>
```